# mac mini server installation fails

Tags: install, mac-mini, osx-server

I am trying to reinstall a clean copy of Leopard Server on my Mac mini server. I have erased both disks and tried to reinstall the OS, but it's always stuck at 36 minutes.

The installation successfully finished once, but then the OS got stuck on the opening screen.

I have checked both disks with disk utility and both appear to be fine.

I would love any suggestions, as I don't know what to do next.

Comment: It would be good to try and locate the installation log file to see where it's hanging. I don't recall if you can get to it from the menu (try pressing command-L and command-3 to see if a log window can be shown during the install). If not, you may have to mount the drive in target mode to read /private/var/log/install.log or similar files...

Comment: If this is still an issue, how are you installing? DVD? DMG? If you are installing from a DVD, there's a chance that it's just bad installation media.

Comment: Could you update this with some more details. Leopard and Snow Leopard server install are both fairly routine so it's often a media issue (DVD) or a hardware issue unrelated to the OS install. Have you run a client OS install or taken any steps to isolate the failure by looking at the installation logs?